# Examine rectified voltage before and after

Tags: bridge-rectifier

I built a simple bridge rectifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcdkFN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I connected the output of the function generator with CH1 of my oscilloscope and 
with the input of the rectifier (using a T-Piece). The output goes into CH2.

The original wave looks like this: 
[image: original wave]

After connecting CH2 the picture looks like this: [image]

While CH2 looks good, 
CH1 now shows the wave I would expect without capacitator but not the expected original wave.

Could somebody explain why? I'm using a Gwinstek GDS-1072A-U Oscilloscope and a Gwinstek SFG-1003 function generator.

Comment: add where you connected the oscilloscope to the circuit (both the probe and the ground)

Comment: what about changing your diodes for rectifiers 1N400X, some diodes can't work as rectifiers.

Comment: 1st: 1n5404 is a rectifier diode. So i would expect that it should be able to work as a rectifier.

2nd: My question is not about the rectifying. As you can see in the second picture the rectifying works pretty good. The question is about why CH1 doesn't show the original wave.

Comment: When you are measuring the voltage across capacitor the ground probe (CH2) is connected to negative terminal of a capacitor right? So where is connected the CH1 probe during this measurements ?

Comment: :D ah, you are using the same equipment to test both signals, when you do that you are bypassing the sine+- to the ground of probe 2 and to negative of C1, this is called a shorcircuit. remember -CH1 is = -CH2. Disconnect -CH1 to see your normal output.

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar thank you very much. Stupid mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your oscilloscope ground connections are shorting out one of the bridge rectifier diodes (D4 by the looks of it).

[image]

Oscilloscope inputs share a common ground connection unless you are using special differential probes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question. While oscilloscopes got a bit neglected in class I once learned that I had to connect + at one end of the point to measure and - to the other.    
Why should I see the correct signal when I connect + to the + generator output and using the ground of -C1?    
I would think that I will get the voltage between +V1 and -C1 and not the expected +V1 and -V1.    

Or in other words: Am I only allowed to measure one point at the same time in the same system?

Comment: You are only allowed to have one common ground connection but you can measure a voltage with both probes simultaneously with respect to that common ground.